# Why can't I use DefaultTableModel? Am I missing something Obvious? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

 class Test{ 
        static CardLayout cardLayout;  
        static JPanel card = new JPanel();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("AddressBook");
            JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
            card.setLayout(cardLayout = new CardLayout());                          

            JPanel cardTop = new JPanel();
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.addColumn("Name");
            model.addColumn("Number");
            String[] John = {"John", "1234"};
            model.addRow(John);
            String[] Beth = {"Beth", "4444"};
            model.addRow(John);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);       
            JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);
            cardTop.add(jsp);


            card.add("Card Top", cardTop);
            contentPane.add(card);

            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(507, 191);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);
        }
    }
```

When I try to compile, it says it doesn't recognize DefaultTableModel. Also, the code above is part of my main and I'm sure I've imported the right libraries.

Here is the error:

```
Test.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            ^
  symbol:   class DefaultTableModel
  location: class Test
Test.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
                                          ^
  symbol:   class DefaultTableModel
  location: class Test
2 errors
```

Help please?

Comment: *"I'm sure I've imported the right libraries"* Sounds like you haven't.  Make sure your importing `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel` or `javax.swing.table.*`

Comment: Can you show the full code? As well as error message.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Compiles fine for me...that implies that you did not import the right libraries...double check those import statements for spelling errors.

Comment: Alright, hold on, I will edit in the full code in a second.

Comment: Okay, There it is. I had to condense it.

Comment: Keep in mind that in Java, the * does not drill down to all child nodes when importing. `import A.*;` will import `A.B`, `A.C`, `A.D`, but not `A.B.C`, `A.B.D`, etc.

Comment: MadProgrammer got the solution don't ignore him just because he is Mad... And Origin has your explanation...

Comment: Add `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel` or `javax.swing.table.*` as MadProgrammer said.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Sorry I never really looked into how * worked. Thanks everyone, sorry for being dumb.

Comment: I'm curious are you using notepad or something because this kind of errors are really hard to get in this age of IDEs and autocompletion...

Comment: I'm using JGrasp LOL. I know it's the worst but It's only my second semester learning Java and I'm too used to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
```

Isn't enough.

`DefaultTableModel` lives in the `javax.swing.table` package, you need to include it in with your imports...

```
import javax.swing.table.*
```